# MySql - Retrieving the last record in each subgroup

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

1.Purchase table

```
Id   user     pur_type
----------------------
1    408       5-12
2    408       5-12
3    222       1-11
4    222       5-12
5    408       1-11
6    408       1-11
```

2. goods table

```
Id   parts    days
-----------------
1    1-11      50
2    5-12      40
```

I implemented such query

```
SELECT p1.id, p1.user, p1.pur_type, g.parts, g.days
FROM purchase p1
INNER JOIN goods g ON p1.pur_type = g.parts
LEFT JOIN goods p2 ON ( p1.pur_type= p2.pur_type
AND p1.id < p2.id )
WHERE p2.id IS NULL
```

The result is only last record for each pur_type

```
Id   user   pur_type  parts   days
---------------------------------
4    222     5-12     5-12    40
6    408     1-11     1-11    50
```

How to get last record from `purchase` table of each `pur_type` for one specific user?

for example for user 408 need result:

```
Id   user     parts   days
-------------------------
2    408       5-12    40
6    408       1-11    50
```

Result explanation:
last record fot `part` 5-12 for user 408 is `id`=2 
last record for `part` 1-11 for user 408 is `id`=6

Comment: Surely `LEFT JOIN goods p2` should be `LEFT JOIN purchase p2` ?

Comment: Is the id column in the goods table in fact redundant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*, c.* -- select columns youw ant
FROM    Purchase a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT user, MAX(ID) max_ID
            FROM    Purchase
            GROUP   BY user, pur_type
        ) b ON  a.user = b.user AND
                a.ID = b.max_ID
        INNER JOIN goods c
            ON a.pur_type = c.parts
WHERE   a.USER = 408
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b487/5)

for better performance, add an INDEX on column `parts` on table `goods` as well on `pur_type`

Answer (score 0):

A simple modification to the existing query:

```
SELECT p1.id, p1.user, p1.pur_type, g.parts, g.days
FROM purchase p1
INNER JOIN goods g ON p1.pur_type = g.parts
LEFT JOIN purchase p2 
       ON ( p1.pur_type= p2.pur_type AND p1.id < p2.id AND p1.user=p2.user)
WHERE p2.id IS NULL and p1.user = 408
```

Comment: the result will be only last record for 408

Comment: @user2054164: This query will return the last record from the purchase table for each `pur_type` for the specified user - see http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b487/11 . Both answers are correct, but this one is closer to your original query.

Comment: thank you for our answer, it will be usefull to get result of last  record for user 408, but i my question i need to get result of last each pur_type type for one specific user

Comment: @user2054164: Please re-read what I just said - this query **will** return the last record from the purchase table **FOR EACH pur_type** for the specified user - see the sqlfiddle linked in the previous comment.